# How to show the side menu in master page selected by default without tapping item of master page in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have to show the menu item selected in master page by default when I call the respective detail page from the previous page.

The way I'm navigating to detail page:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)    
{
    masterDetailPage = new MainMasterDetailPage();                   
    masterDetailPage.ID = 1;        
    await Navigation.PushAsync(masterDetailPage, false);    
}
```

Getting detail page but side menu item is not showing selected:

```
switch (ID)
{
   case 1:
   page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(secondPage));    
   break;
}
Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

Comment: Are you using the List to Populate the Menu on the Master page ? Can you share the Xaml of your Menu page!

Comment: <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"  >                <ListView.ItemTemplate>  <DataTemplate><customControls:ExtendedViewCell x:Name="extendedCell" ><ViewCell.View> <StackLayout  >< Label   Text="{BindingMenuTitle}"   />  </StackLayout> </ViewCell.View></customControls:ExtendedViewCell>  </DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate>     </ListView>